# Loading of javascript file

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm new to working with javascript & I'm learning more & more every day.
I have some questions regarding the very basics of the loading, execution & defer loading of javascript. The more I search & read about this on different sites the more confused I get...

Questions:

**1. Loading of external files in the `<head>` vs. loading of these files in the end of document & just before `</body>`.**

What is the difference here?
What I've come to understand is that when placing the loading just before `</body>` then loading of the document happens before the js is executed. But what about *rendering* of the document? Is the rendering of the document also happening before the js is executed? Like so:

1 Loading of document

2 Rendering of document

3 Loading of js-files

4 Execution of js

**2. Defer loading of js-files. I've read Google's recomendations for js-loading. My question here is kind of the same as above. When is the actual *rendering* of the document taking place?**

Google recomends using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "your-js-file.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Is the order here as follows?:

1 Loading of document

2 Loading of js-files

3 Execution of js

4 Rendering of document

Really hope someone can share some light on this for me...
Best, Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the attempt from google right before body ends the order is :

1. Loading of document
2. rendering of doument
3. execution of js in document(google-suggest-code)
4. loading external js
5. execution of external js

But if you want to include a library like jquery and you have depending code in your document,
i would rather  load the library in `<head>`

and the depending js-code right before the body ends insider a document ready wrap

so the order would be

1. Loading of document and external ressources
2. rendering document
3. execute js in document

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions.
What exactly does depending js-code mean? 
Is this code that for example change the visuals of a page?

Comment: for example: you include jQuery as external ressource and in your document you have jquery-script, that jquery script wont run if there is no jquery library, so there is a dependecy

Answer (score 0):

1. HTML rendering is a gradual process which means the browser will not wait until all HTML is parsed before starting to render.
2. Scripts may be blocked by unloaded style sheets.
3. A script will block the parsing of the document until the script is fetched and executed.

So style sheets should be placed in `<head>` for gradual rendering. Scripts should be placed before `</body>` to avoid blocking.

[How browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

Comment: Ok thank you for taking the time to answer my quations.
But what does window.onload do?
Is this the same as putting the loading of an js-file in the end of a document?
Thanks for the link!

Comment: @NiklasWideC window.onload will be fired when the DOM tree and its content (images, css, scripts, etc.) are loaded. So they are not the same. Putting scripts before `</body>` is more like `document.ready` which will be fired when DOM tree is loaded.